# What is the cleanest way to implement if/not in ERB in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, erb

Consider the following code from index view:

```
<td>
  <%= 'foo' if bar == BAZ %>
  <%= 'qux' if bar != BAZ %>
</td>
```

Is this the cleanest way to do this, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems like a good case for a [ternary conditional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Ruby):

```
<%= bar == BAZ ? 'foo' : 'qux' %>
```

Barring that, a plain old if/else:

```
<%= if bar == BAZ then 'foo'
    else 'qux'
    end
%>
```